# Set value to the "preheader" of a design in sendgrid API

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid API to create/update/delete a Design.
as you can see in the picture below, there isn't any JSON item to set the value for the "preheader"

[image: sendGrid document]

So after creating successfully in the Sendgrid design library the preheader is empty and we should fill it by editing the design. picture below

[image]

Is there any solution to set the value to the preheader with API?

Comment: Check out this SO post which answers the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788422/sendgrid-where-to-set-preheader-when-sending-html-dynamic-template-via-web-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sendgrid ~ where to set preheader when sending HTML Dynamic Template via Web Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788422/sendgrid-where-to-set-preheader-when-sending-html-dynamic-template-via-web-api)

Comment: Somehow it mentions the solution but not exactly. because this solution just works for the Dynamic Email Template. But Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution. As Philnash has mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788422/sendgrid-where-to-set-preheader-when-sending-html-dynamic-template-via-web-api) the pre-header is located in the body of the Email Design Html. But we should use some **attributes** which **are very important**.

Just append these 2 nested div with a p tag to the body of your Html-content. Then send it to the SendGrid

```
<div class="module preheader preheader-hide" role="module" data-type="preheader">
       <div role="module-content" style="display: none!important; mso-hide: 
          all; visibility: hidden; ">
                <p id="preheaderId"> your pre header </p>
       </div> 
</div>
```